# Unity3d Transfer of value from one script to another

Tags: c#, unity, unityscript

Script 1

```
public class enemy : MonoBehaviour {
    private Vector3 Player;
    private Vector2 PlayerDirection;
    public float Xdif;
    public float Ydif;
    private float speed;
    private float distance;
    private bool stun;
    private float stuntime;
    GameObject playerObj;
    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody2D;
    private bool isEnemyFear;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
  stuntime = 0;
  stun = false;
  speed = 6;
  playerObj = GameObject.Find ("Player");
  myRigidbody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update () {
  distance = Vector2.Distance (Player, transform.position);
  Player = playerObj.transform.position;
  if (stuntime > 0) {
   stuntime -=Time.deltaTime;
  } else {
   stun = false;
  }
  if(isEnemyFear){  //here to pass a value from script 2
   EnemyFear();
  }
  else{
   EnemyAttack();
  }

    }
    void EnemyAttack(){

  if (distance < 25 & !stun) {
   Xdif = Player.x - transform.position.x;
   Ydif = Player.y - transform.position.y;
   PlayerDirection = new Vector2 (Xdif, Ydif);
   myRigidbody2D.AddForce (PlayerDirection.normalized * speed);
   Debug.Log("Attack");
  }    
    }

    void EnemyFear(){

  if (distance < 25 & !stun) {
   Xdif = Player.x + transform.position.x;
   Ydif = Player.y + transform.position.y;
   PlayerDirection = new Vector2 (Xdif, Ydif);
   myRigidbody2D.AddForce (PlayerDirection.normalized * speed);
   Debug.Log("Fear");
  }
  StartCoroutine(Timer());
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D Playerhit){
  if (Playerhit.gameObject.CompareTag("Player")) {
   stun = true;
   stuntime = 1;
  }
    }
    IEnumerator Timer() {
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);
  isEnemyFear = false;
  StopCoroutine ("Timer");
    }

}
```

Script 2

```
public class randomizer : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool isEnemyFear;

    public void CheckFear(){
  int rand = Random.Range(0, 100);
  if(rand > 35)
   isEnemyFear = true; //this value should be passed to the script 1
    }

}
```

How to pass a value `isEnemyFear = true` from Script 2 in Script 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `isEnemyFear` is declared as `private` in both scripts which means it is not exposed to other scripts and can not be read or set by them.

But if you would declare is as `public` and when you have both scripts on the same game object, you could set it from one script in the other by getting that script with `GetComponent`. So you could either have the `randomizer` component modify the data of the `enemy` component with

```
 GetComponent<enemy>().isEnemyFear = true;
```

or have the `enemy` component pull the data from the `randomizer` with

```
if (GetComponent<randomizer>().isEnemyFear) {
```

Note that in both cases it is very likely redundant to have that variable in both components.

When these two components are on different game objects, you first need a reference to the other one, so you can use `otherGameObject.GetComponent`. There are different ways to do that, like having a variable for it which you set in the inspector, using `GameObject.Find("name")` (warning: slow) or when one game object instantiates the other, retaining the reference. Which one you should use depends on how your project is structured.